# How do avoid SQL Injection as per OWSAP in the query

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, sql-injection

I am using `entimanager` to execute db queries in spring boot app

```
 String query = "select name, dept from employee";
 int count = ((Long) em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from  (" + query + ") query")
            .getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

But as per `OWSAP` there is `SQL Injection`  issue at `" + query + "` I tried  `.setParameter(1, query)` But its throwing SQL Grammer Exception.

I have learnt that if i will sanitize the param like

```
  Codec ORACLE_CODEC = new OracleCodec();
  ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC, **query**)
```

Security issue will go off. Is there any alternative of `OracleCodec` like to `PostGresCodec`
since i am using postgres and also is it goot to use `ESAPI` as its already outdated. Or is there any better library like `apache common` to sanatize the params.

Comment: why you're making it in two steps? Why don't you do it just "select count(*) from  (select name, dept from employee) query". How does this query make any sense by the way?

Comment: Since "query" in your example is not derived from use input or from the environment, there is no vulnerability there in the first place.

Comment: @jjanes this is one sample API . There any such api where i am building query from user inputs.